# What does `tf.keras.Model.compile` do in TF2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In TF2.0, it is still necessary to call `model.compile` after creating a keras model, as seen in the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#set_up_training).

But with eager mode, there is no need for graph creation, so what is the use of `tf.keras.Model.compile` in Tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.compile` has nothing to do with graph mode, it defines the loss, optimizer, and metrics, same as with `keras` and `tf.keras` in  TF 1.x. The graph is just an internal detail that is not really related to `model.compile`.